# how to show li one by one with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

what im trying to do is show li text one by one i have lets say tag 1, tag 2, tag 3 ... first time to show tag 1 after that tag 2 after that tag 3 and so on ... one by one ...

the code what i work on it is this:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>tag 1</li>
    <li>tag 2</li>
    <li>tag 3</li>
    <li>tag 4</li>
    <li>tag 5</li>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul > li').each(function(){
        $(this).hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(1850);
        _self = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url     : '/echo/json/',
            data    : {
                text : _self.val()
            },
            type    : 'POST',
            success : function(response) {
                _self.css('color','red');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FWZKF/2/

Comment: url     : '/echo/json/'???

Comment: What was the ajax call for ? if you only needed the fadein

Answer (score 4):

increase the delay on each element:

```
$('ul > li').each(function(i){
        $(this).hide().delay(i*1000).fadeIn(1850);}
  //more code
);
```

Comment: just finished this: http://jsfiddle.net/FWZKF/5/ and you beat me to it, good answer.

Comment: thanks ! this is what i search for ! thanks abc123 and Dr.Molle

Answer (score 1):

You could use the animation callback to go to next element, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/xuKH3/

```
    iterator( $('ul > li').hide().first() );
    function iterator( el ) {
        el.fadeIn(1850, function() { iterator( el.next() ); } )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- `.delay()` only delays animations. It doesn't actually delay your code. Either process each `<li>` only after the previous has finished or make it seem that way by delaying the fade in longer for elements lower in the `<ul>`.
- `_self` is a global variable (you omitted `var`), so all of the callbacks will make only the last element red, as that's what the value of `_self` will be by the time they're called. You need to make it local to the callback function.

Comment: fadeIn is an animation

Comment: @Dr.Molle: It is. From what I can tell, OP is trying to use it like a `sleep()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Another method, not as great as Dr.Molle.

http://jsfiddle.net/FWZKF/8/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').hide();
    var shown = $('ul > li:first');
    shown.hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(1850);
    setInterval(function(){
        if(shown.next().length){
            shown = shown.next();
             shown.hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(1850);
        }
    },2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use css `transition-delay` property for this and scss to increment it for each `<li>` element

> https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp

```
    $delay-increment: 0.3;
    $delay: 0-$delay-increment;

    @for $i from 1 through 10 { //adding transition delays to provide sequential icons show on profile load
        li:nth-child(#{$i}) {
            transition-delay: #{$delay+$delay-increment}s;

            &:after{
                transition-delay: #{$delay+$delay-increment}s;
            }
        }

        $delay: $delay + $delay-increment;
    }
```

to show `<li>` I use JS just to set class `show` which is responsible for opacity change

see example with compiled sass below:

```js
$('.show').click(function() {
  $('ul').toggleClass('show');
})
```

```css
li:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}

li:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0.9s;
}

li:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: 1.2s;
}

li:nth-child(6) {
  transition-delay: 1.5s;
}

li:nth-child(7) {
  transition-delay: 1.8s;
}

li:nth-child(8) {
  transition-delay: 2.1s;
}

li:nth-child(9) {
  transition-delay: 2.4s;
}

li:nth-child(10) {
  transition-delay: 2.7s;
}

ul>li {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .4s;
}

ul.show>li {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='show'>Show</button>

<ul>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
</ul>
```